# Android Volley - NoRouteToHoseException Error

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am trying to POST registration details to a localhost db but seem to be getting an error "NoConnectionError: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host when on wifi. When on data, I get a Volley time out error. No information is posted to the db. I'm trying to pull db_functions.php which is stored in my www (WAMP) folders in my C drive. I've seen many examples doing the same thing but I can't seem to get mine to work.

I've posted all my code below, any help would be appreciated.

Registration page (JobSeekerSignUp.java)

```
 public class JobSeekerSignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView jobHaveAccount;
private TextView jobFirstName;
private TextView jobLastName;
private TextView jobEmailAddress;
private TextView jobPassword;
private Button jobSubmit;
String URL = "http://192.168.0.9/db_functions.php";


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_seeker_sign_up);



    jobHaveAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobHaveAccount);
    jobFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobFirstName);
    jobLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobLastName);
    jobEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobEmailAddress);
    jobPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobPassword);
    jobSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jobSubmit);


    jobHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent jobSeekerSignIn = new Intent(JobSeekerSignUp.this, 
 JobSeekerLogIn.class);
            startActivity(jobSeekerSignIn);
        }
    });

    jobSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String userFirstName = 
 jobFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String userLastName = 
 jobLastName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String userEmailAddress = 
 jobEmailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            final String userPassword = 
 jobPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            RequestQueue queue = 
 Volley.newRequestQueue(JobSeekerSignUp.this);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
 URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(JobSeekerSignUp.this, response, 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("My Success", "" + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(JobSeekerSignUp.this, "My Error :" + 
  error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("My Error", "" + error);
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws 
    AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("jobFirstName", userFirstName);
                    map.put("jobLastName", userLastName);
                    map.put("jobEmailAddress", userEmailAddress);
                    map.put("jobPassword", userPassword);

                    return map;
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

db_functions.php

```
 <?php
 $fName = $_POST['jobFirstName'];
 $lName = $_POST['jobLastName'];
 $emailAdd = $_POST['jobEmailAddress'];
 $password = $_POST['jobPassword'];
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "";
  $host = "localhost";
  $dbname = "discover";

 $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
 $sql="insert into jobseekerusers(jobSeekerFirstName, jobSeekerLastName, 
 jobSeekerEmailAddress, jobSeekerPassword) 
 Values ('".$fName."','".$lName."','".$emailAdd."','".$password."');
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
  echo 'Data Inserted';
 }else {
 echo 'Failed';
  }



  ?>
```

Comment: I noticed that there is an error in the statement that assigns value to variable named sql. But I don't think that this is the reason for your error shown above

Comment: Are you sure that `http://192.168.0.9` is correct for your localhost ????

Comment: @NIKHILNEDIYODATH - Please share.

Comment: @HarinKaklotar - I doubled check and found the IPv4 to be 192.168.0.14 so I have updated it however now experiencing Volley timeout error and no data being posted.

Answer (score 0):

**db_functions.php**

```
<?php
 $fName = $_POST['jobFirstName'];
 $lName = $_POST['jobLastName'];
 $emailAdd = $_POST['jobEmailAddress'];
 $password = $_POST['jobPassword'];
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "";
  $host = "localhost";
  $dbname = "discover";

 $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
 $sql="insert into jobseekerusers(jobSeekerFirstName, jobSeekerLastName, 
 jobSeekerEmailAddress, jobSeekerPassword) 
 Values ('".$fName."','".$lName."','".$emailAdd."','".$password."')";
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
  echo 'Data Inserted';
 }else {
 echo 'Failed';
}
?>
```